# Using ng-repeat in table format

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following array in my module in `Angular.js`:

```
$scope.hsbody = []; //Data array
$scope.hsresult = []; //Data array
$scope.hsProcess = []; //Boolean array
$scope.hssuccess = []; //Boolean array
$scope.hsfailure = []; //Boolean array
$scope.hsExpand = []; //Boolean array
$scope.hsExpandUser = []; //Boolean array
```

I want to show the array items in my Html page:

```
hsresult
hsbody
hsresult
hsbody
and so on..
```

So I do the following:

```
    <div>
        <pre>
            <table class="table table-condensed">
                  <tr ng-repeat="hs in hsbody track by $i" ng-show="hsProcess[i] && !hssuccess[i] && !hsfailure[i]" class="warning"><td><div class="glyphicon"></div>{{hsbody}}</td></tr>
                  <tr ng-show="hssuccess" ng-repeat="highstate in hsbody track by $i" class="success"><td><div class="glyphicon" ng-show="!hsExpand[i]"></div><div class="glyphicon" ng-show="hsExpand[i]"></div>{{ hsresult[i] }} </td></tr>
                  <tr ng-show="hsfailure" ng-repeat="hs in hsbody track by $i" class="danger"><td><div class="glyphicon" ng-show="!hsExpand"></div><div class="glyphicon" ng-show="hsExpand[i]"></div>{{ hsresult[i] }}</td></tr>
                  <tr ng-repeat="hs in hsbody track by $i" ng-show="(hsProcess[i] && hsExpand[i]) || (hsExpand[i] && hsfailure[i])" class="active"><td><pre>{{ hsbody[i] }}</pre></td></tr>
            </table>
        </pre>
    </div>
```

The problem is that nothing is shown in my HTML. but when I get rid of the `ng-repeat` and use `i=0`, then I can see the values.

It seems that I don't use the `ng-repeat` correctly, but I don't know where I wrong.

Comment: whats `$i` in track by?

Comment: @K.Toress: Can you please clarify the question? What I try to do is to take all the items in hsbody, and iterate over them by using the `$i` index. I know that `hsbody.length = hsresult.result = hsProcess.length = and so on`, so I use the `$i` value for each one of the arrays.

Comment: Why don't you just properly reorganize the data in the controller?  That's what I think you should do.

Comment: i think u need to use `$index` instead of `$i`

Comment: @K.Toress: I change all i occurrences with index, but the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside anything with 'ng-repeat' you'll have to reference everything through whatever you specified in the ng-repeat.

e.g. say you had an array, 'main', in the controller 'data'.

You have usernames in objects within data.main

```
$scope.main = [
    {username: 'jeff'},
    {username: 'brad'},
]
```

or

```
this.main = [
    {username: 'jeff'},
    {username: 'brad'},
]
```

If you wrote

```
<div ng-repeat="theData in data.main track by $i">
    {{ data.main.username }}
</div>
```

an error would come up, because it's undefined.

If you wrote

```
<div ng-repeat="theData in data.main track by $i">
    {{ theData.username }}
</div>
```

you would get what you wanted.

The reason is that you are specifying theData as the source of everything inside the ng-repeat.

theData is equivalent to data.main, for inside the ng-repeat

You can't access anything outside the object data.main inside the div.

If you need anything from outside, think again. Do you really want that data printed however many times?

Comment: If it doesn't work, try it with track by `$index`. You may need to add `$index` up there with `$scope` at the top of your controller `app.controller('ExapmleCtrl', function($scope, $index){...});`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the "track by" with index, you should write there: "track by $index".
good luck!

Comment: I change all i occurrences with index, but the same

Answer (score 0):

this works for you?

```
    <div>
    <pre>
        <table class="table table-condensed">
            <tr ng-repeat="hs in hsbody track by $index" ng-show="hsProcess[$index] && !hssuccess[$index] && !hsfailure[$index]" class="warning">
                <td>
                    <div class="glyphicon"></div>{{hs}}
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-show="hssuccess" ng-repeat="highstate in hsbody track by $index" class="success">
                <td>
                    <div class="glyphicon" ng-show="!hsExpand[i]"></div>
                    <div class="glyphicon" ng-show="hsExpand[$index]"></div>{{ hsresult[$index] }} 
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-show="hsfailure" ng-repeat="hs in hsbody track by $index" class="danger">
                <td>
                    <div class="glyphicon" ng-show="!hsExpand"></div>    
                    <div class="glyphicon" ng-show="hsExpand[i]"></div>{{ hsresult[$index] }}
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="hs in hsbody track by $index" ng-show="(hsProcess[$index] && hsExpand[$index]) || (hsExpand[$index] && hsfailure[$index])" class="active">
                <td>
                    <pre>{{ hsbody[$index] }}</pre>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </pre>
</div>
```